# Access selected item of RecyclerView to delete it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm using recyclerView on my app. I have a global list of object (Route). In my calendar, when I click on a specific day, another list is created with the Route done that day.

The thing is that I now want to delete a Route of the calendar.

I don't know why but it does not take the correct position..

Here's my adapter class

```
package ch.hearc.hikoo.ui.preview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import ch.hearc.hikoo.R;
import ch.hearc.hikoo.route.Route;
import ch.hearc.hikoo.route.Surfacing;
import ch.hearc.hikoo.tools.DialogTools;
import ch.hearc.hikoo.ui.preview.PreviewFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener;
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class PreviewRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PreviewRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    //Callback
    private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    //Input
    private final List<Route> mRoutes;
    private final Context mContext;
    private final Activity mActivity;



    public PreviewRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Route> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener, Context context, Activity activity) {
        mRoutes = items;
        mListener = listener;
        mContext = context;
        mActivity = activity;
    }





    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_preview, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Route route = mRoutes.get(position);

        //Init view data
        holder.mItem = route;
        holder.mName.setText(route.getName());
        holder.mDistance.setText(String.format("%.1f km", route.getLength() / 1000));
        holder.mTime.setText(Route.convertMinuteToHour(route.getDuration()));
        holder.mSurfacingNatural.setText(String.format("%.0f%% %s", route.getNaturalSurfacing(), Surfacing.NATURAL.getName(mContext)));
        holder.mSurfacingHard.setText(String.format("%.0f%% %s", route.getHardSurfacing(), Surfacing.HARD.getName(mContext)));
        holder.mLevel.setText(route.getLevel().getName(mContext));
        holder.mElevationGain.setText(String.format("+ %s m", route.getElevationGain()));
        holder.mElevationLoss.setText(String.format("- %s m", route.getElevationLoss()));

        //Color of the circle image
        int color = PreviewFragment.createColorFromPosition(position);
        holder.mCircleImage.setFillColor(color);
        holder.mCircleImage.setBorderColor(color);

        //On item click
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (null != mListener) {
                mListener.onPreviewItemClicked(position);
                if (holder.isSelected) {
                    holder.mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    holder.isSelected = false;
                } else {
                    holder.mView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, (R.color.accent_light)));
                    holder.isSelected = true;
                }
            }
        });



        //On item long click
        holder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            DialogTools.displayRouteInfoDialog(mActivity, route);
            return true;
        });

                   holder.mView.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            if (holder.isSelected) {
                holder.mView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, (R.color.accent_light)));
                mRoutes.remove(route);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                holder.isSelected = false;
            } else {
                holder.mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                holder.isSelected = true;
            }

        });



        //Select first item by default
       if (position == 0) {
            holder.mView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, (R.color.accent_light)));
            holder.isSelected = true;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mRoutes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mName;
        public final TextView mDistance;
        public final TextView mSurfacingNatural;
        public final TextView mSurfacingHard;
        public final TextView mTime;
        public final TextView mLevel;
        public final TextView mElevationGain;
        public final TextView mElevationLoss;
        public CircleImageView mCircleImage;
        public Route mItem;
        public boolean isSelected;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_route_name);
            mDistance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_route_distance);
            mSurfacingNatural = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_route_surfacing_naturel);
            mSurfacingHard = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_route_surfacing_hard);
            mTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_route_time);
            mLevel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_route_level);
            mElevationGain = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_route_gain);
            mElevationLoss = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_route_loss);
            mCircleImage = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.circle_image_route);
            isSelected = false;
        }


        public String getName()
        {
            return (String) this.mName.getText();
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mName.getText() + "'";
        }


    }
}
```

how I instanciate the adapter in my fragment :

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_preview);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mAdapter = new PreviewRecyclerViewAdapter(listRouteDayClicked, mCallback, getContext(), getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
```

I can access the position, but how do I pass it to my method that is in my fragment and not in my adapterclass ? The method is called after a click on button of my fragment

Comment: Can't see where do you call List.remove() method { mRoutes.remove(position) }. Please show us where do you call this method so we will be able to help you

Comment: @Royi sry I edited now.

Comment: @David    mRoutes.remove(route); instead of route pass adapter position

Answer (score 0):

Create an Interface like

```
interface OnRouteClickListener{
    void onRoutClicked(Route route)
}
```

Then pass instance of this interface to adapter constructor and call onRoutClicked() in OnClick() method

```
//...
    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        routeListener(route)

    });
    //...
```

To use this OnRouteClickListener in your Fragment initialize the adapter this way:

```
mAdapter = new PreviewRecyclerViewAdapter(listRouteDayClicked, mCallback, getContext(), getActivity(), new OnRouteClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRoutClicked(Route route) {
            //do what you want to do with the clicked route
        }
    });
```

Now you can apply all the logic in the fragment that owned this adapter.

You can also pass an integer, to this interface method, that represent the item position instead of the Route object

Comment: and what do I have to do to get the item or the route selected in my fragment ?

Comment: The answer has been edited according to your question